# What is the chance of paralysis on an enchanted weapon?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

If I've enchanted my weapon to paralyze on hit, what are the odds that it will proc?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

According to UESP, the chance of paralysis on a weapon enchanted with Paralysis effect is 25%.

I have confirmed the 25% number with empirical testing.

### Test Data:

Number of Hits between Paralysis:

**Giant**: 3 11 12 8 1 1 2 4 2 1 5 4 3 3 1 1 4 7 5 9 7 10 2 9 1 6 1 4 10 3 1 1 3 1 2 2 4 2 1

**Average**: 4.02

**Count**: 39

**Implied chance of paralysis**: 24.9%

---

**Bandit Marauder**: 1 4 1 1 14 1 2 6 7 10 5 1 3 15 6 8 4 1 1 1 7 16 1 3 1 1 9 1 2

**Average**: 4.59

**Count**: 29

**Implied chance of paralysis**: 21.8%

---

**Total Average**: 4.26

**Count**: 68

**Implied chance of paralysis**: 23.4%

(Close enough for the small sample size, I say.)

**Source**: [UESP Weapon Effects](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Enchanting_Effects#Weapon_Effects)

Comment: Wow, sir, wow, I tip my hat to you.